# How to modify NSURLRequest http method in iOS11?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlrequest, nsmutableurlrequest

I am loading `NSMutableURLRequest` in `WKWebView` on iOS 11 and getting a white screen. Once I change `NSMutableURLRequest` to `NSURLRequest`, and avoid this white screen view case But I want to add http method. Can anyone help me with this?

I already add this in info.plist.
[image]

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) WKWebView *webView;

if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
} else {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:180];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];                        
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a NSURLRequest (not mutable) you can include the method in the url itself.

```
method="get|post"
```

But I don't understand what's going on with that white screen :S